# Face Recognition with opencv4 with python

Tags: python-3.x

I am developing a face recognition program and i have used only opencv with python. But my application is not working with 100% accuracy. How to increase accuracy only in opencv code.

Comment: I'm going to assume that "accuracy" refers to the test accuracy. In practice, it's really really hard to attain 100% accuracy on a model, depending on what problem you're trying to solve. Increasing accuracy is often a matter of clever feature selection, good model tuning, and patience, so it's really difficult to help you out.

Comment: yeah but my problem is about that cascade file i have used. How can i train my model to get more accurate data that will store in .yaml file. Is there any solution for haarcascade to get more accuracy???